# issue while adding ConstraintLayout to RelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have just started using `ConstraintLayout`, I have already Created layout using ConstraintLayout. Here is XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintSetLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id_question_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/game_question_display"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.55" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_option_four"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_10dp"
        android:text="@string/game_option_four"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_option_three"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_option_two" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_option_three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/game_option_three"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_option_four"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/id_option_one" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_option_one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/game_option_one"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/id_option_three"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/id_option_two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_option_two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/game_option_two"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/id_option_four"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/id_option_one"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline4" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have inflated this view and trying to add this view in `RelativeLayout` programmatically. But after adding inflated view (ConstraintLayout) get shrinks to top of screen. Please Check Image [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7gcavufnm3envab/device-2017-12-08-134325.png?dl=0)

I have tried using `ConstraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, but no change.

Here is the RelativeLayout code which i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.radio.constraintlayoutapp.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeTest"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/RamandeepKaurSidhu/ConstraintLayout) for code on Github

Comment: and what do you want to achieve? what is your final goal?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8t2m5qr8l9dn1cr/device-2017-12-08-134430.png?dl=0 this view

Comment: ViewGroup parentLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        setContentView(parentLayout);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inner, parentLayout);

Comment: you can also use `ConstraintLayout` / `RelativeLayout` as a `parentLayout` but `FrameLayout` is the easiest one

Comment: thanks its working fine when using frame layout

Comment: it works with ConstraintLayout / RelativeLayout too - what you will choose it all depends what  you need parent layout for